# Запись элементов стека в другой стек

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, циклы, стек

Я хочу из данного мне стека сделать стек без нечетных чисел.

Структура:

```
typedef struct Node {
Node *pNext;
int value; } Node;
```

Функции создания, вывода стека:

```
    void create(Node **head) {
    int n, data;
    if (*head != NULL) {
        cout << "Please Clear memory!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Enter count of elements" << endl;
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            data = rand() % 20 + 1;
            push(head, data);
        }
    }
}


void push(Node **head, int data) {
    Node *tmp = new Node;
    tmp->value = data;
    tmp->pNext = (*head);
    (*head) = tmp;
}

void print(Node *head) {
    Node *tmp = head;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        cout << " " << tmp->value << endl;
        tmp = tmp->pNext;
    }
}
```

Вот функция перезаписи эл-ов в новый стек:

```
void individual(Node *head) {
    Node *head2 = NULL; int data;
    while (head != NULL) {
        if ((head->value) % 2 == 0) {
            data = head->value;
            push(&head2, data);
            head = head->pNext;
        }
        else {
            head = head->pNext;
        }

        print(head2);
    }   
}
```

При исходном стеке 3 16 12 2 8,

вывод во второй стек будет таким:
16 12 16 2 12 16 8 2 12 16

Comment: В чем собственно проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите вызов функции печати стека `print` из цикла `while`

```
void individual(Node *head) {
    Node *head2 = NULL; int data;
    while (head != NULL) {
        if ((head->value) % 2 == 0) {
            data = head->value;
            push(&head2, data);
            head = head->pNext;
        }
        else {
            head = head->pNext;
        }
    }   

    print(head2);
}
```

И лучше переписать эту функцию таким образом, чтобы она создавала и возвращала новый стек, который уж затем после вызова этой функции можно будет вывести на консоль.

Например,

```
Node * individual( Node *head ) 
{
    Node *head2 = NULL;

    for ( ; head; head = head->pNext )
    {
        if ( head->value % 2 == 0 ) 
        {
            push( &head2, head->value );
        }

    }

    return head2;
}
```

и в `main` вызывать эту функцию как

```
Node *head2 = individual( head );
print( head2 );
```